# image resize within div (again)

Tags: css, html, resize

There are a few posts about this subject going around, i know, but i really can't find a solution that will solve my problem around..
I have a testing site, which i'm using to show up my questions so far. I made a simple layout, with a header, a left div, a right div, and a footer. each one has a very different color in order to being easier to identify them. My problem lies with resizing the background img of the header. 
I tried inserting the background-size:100% trick, but if i put only that, yes, it will strech to fit the div's width (as intended) but the height will be all messed up.. it will be like 20px in height. I intend to have it filling the height accordingly. 
I tried to set the div height to the max img size. That will solve the problem only when site is maxed (since div height is a fixed valor, if the site is at maxed, all will show ok, but if i shrink window, the pic will get smaller both in width and height, but the div will be the same size, thus showing the greenish background as show in the example)...

In sum, is there any way to make that gradient background image follow the div height size as well as width?

here's my testing link to show you what i've got so far ( i let it with fixed div height ).

http://www.testingflash.net76.net/IGG.php

here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>IGG</title>
<link href="igg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!--wrapper starts--> 
<div id="main1">content</div>
<div id="left">content</div>
<div id="right"><div><embed width="100%" height="600px" loop="false"
src="photogallery_with_scroll2.swf"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
</div><!--end wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the css:

```
#wrapper {
background-color: #96F;
width: 96%;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-left: 2%;
}

#main1 {
background-color: #CF6;
background-image: url(header_gradient.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:200px;
}

#left {
background-color: #6CC;
float: left;
width: 44%;
margin-right: 1%;
}

#footer {
background-color: #03F;
clear: both;
}

#right {
background-color: #F36;
float: right;
margin-left: 1%;
width: 50%;
}
```

Notice that if you shrink down the testing site, the green background of the div will show. If i remove the --- height:200px --- from the css stylesheet, the height will be shrinked to a thin line..

so..help pretty pls? ;)
thank you very much in advance..

Comment: is it an option to use CSS gradients instead of a .png image?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients

Comment: You should use gradient property instead of gradient.png

Comment: @Ani Bear in mind that if you use a Gradient, it isn't supported very well, particuarly in IE, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: Well some of them are if you use filter attribute

Comment: well, in the example it's a gradient img, but in the real site i intend to use a photo, so i'm afraid i can't use the gradient property...

Comment: Yes **some**. Only IE10+ though, which like it or not is probably still, what, 50% of traffic?

Comment: @Liam: Following works in IE8 and above. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
.css3gradient{
     background-color:#43493f;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#43493f, endColorstr=#848079);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #43493f 0%, #848079 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #43493f 0%, #848079 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #43493f 0%, #848079 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(left, #43493f 0%, #848079 100%);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #43493f 0%, #848079 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#43493f), color-stop(100%,#848079));
```

Comment: i think i shoudn't have used a gradient img as an example.. ^^ like i said above, i used a gradient img merely as an example. What i really need to know (since it's what i will use in the real site) is how to do the height resizing trick with any .png img.

Comment: Yes. Everybody got side track from question :P

Comment: @user2501765 Have you tried background-position: 'top center' in css

Answer (score 0):

Okay Got it working:

```
#main1 {
   background-color: #CF6;
   background-image: url(header_gradient.png);
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nop..didn't work.. now the height is working, but the width will not fit the whole div.. the image will not stretch beyond its original size... you can see the results on the testing site...

http://www.testingflash.net76.net/IGG.php

Comment: You have to use property background-size: cover; Check the above post css and tally with urs.

Comment: edit: changed the image to better view the results.. as you can see yosemite san is not resizing at all!!!

Comment: you don't have property 
#main1{background-size: cover;}

Comment: sorry, hadn't notice you had already replied when i answered you... Added the background-size:cover... result is still not as intended,  since the image will indeed stretch to full div size when maximized, but on the other hand the image will now be cut when the site is shrinked...

Comment: sure... i'm updating the testing site with the answers u have been giving me... testing site is here:  testingflash.net76.net/IGG.php                                      As for the css stylesheet, it's like this now:

Comment: sorry, ran out of space ^^ here's the css:                         #wrapper {
 background-color: #96F;
 width: 96%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
}
        #main1 {
 background-color: #CF6;
 background-image: url(test.png);
        background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height:200px;
        width:100%;

        }
        #left {
 background-color: #6CC;
 float: left;
 width: 44%;
 margin-right: 1%;
        }

        #footer {
 background-color: #03F;
 clear: both;
         }
        #right {
 background-color: #F36;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 1%;
 width: 50%;
   }

Comment: newest update: someone else advised me to remove the background-size:cover and replace with background size 100% 100%; the second 100% did indeed do the trick. Now only one problem left to solve. The image will be distorted when the site shrinks down because the div has a fixed height of 200px. I tried using max-height:200px (since i never want the div to go over 200px, no matter the screen size) but if i do that, the div collapses again to the tiny 20px line.. So, any way to make the div height proportionally follow the width %?